# Optimize mobile web app by hiding or removing elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I'm creating a mobile version of a web application I have recently made. I am trying to optimize the application to make it as fast as possible. There are some elements inside the application that should not be visible for the mobile version.

How should I go about dealing with these elements?

Do I use JavaScript to completely remove the element from the DOM? Do I use a CSS media query and simply change the visibility of the element to hidden? Do I use JavaScript and change the visibility of the element to hidden?

I'm looking for the most efficient way as my objective is to improve performance (even if it's only a very small difference).

Comment: Just hiding or changing the visibility of elements does not reduce the page weight. It might cut page rendering times but removing them from the DOM (or rather not adding them) at mobile sizes would be of greater value.

Answer (score 0):

As u said it should optimized for the performance. One thing to keep in mind is using images of right size. for this you can use css background-image to some elements and use css media query to select the right size background-image.

Eg:

```
#banner{
background-image: big-image.jpg;
}

@media all and (max-width: 640px){
#banner{
background-image: small-image.jpg;
}
}

@media all and (max-width: 420px){
#banner{
background-image: tiny-image.jpg;
}
}
```

for rest of the elements you can just remove() if really bulky html or hide if its very few lines.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid loading desktop images on mobile devices there is a nice trick to lazy load them by adding data attributes to the image tags instead of src.

```
 <img data-lazy-load-event="immediately" data-lazy-load-for-media="desktop" data-lazy-load-src="image.jpg" />
```

In JavaScript you can search your DOM for all images with the data-lazy-load-src and then load them according to their media type, by adding the data-lazy-load-src attribute to their src attribute.

For elements that you can't avoid loading, use JavaScript to remove them from the DOM.